# Using match to find substrings in strings with only bash

Tags: regex, bash, match

Although I am almost sure this has been covered, I can't seem to find anything specific to this. As I continue my journey on learning bash I keep finding parts where I am baffled as to why things happen the way they do.

Searching and replacing or just matching sub-strings in strings is most likely one of the first thing you do when writing scripts. But, trying to stick to one single language or set of tools is difficult to do in bash, as you are able to solve most problem in multiple ways. I am doing my best to stay as low level as possible with bash. I have run into a snag that I need someone to explain to me.

Doing sub-string a search in bash with match gives me different results depending on the regular expression I use, and I am not sure why.

```
#!/bin/bash
Stext="Hallo World"
echo `expr "$Stext" : '^\(.[a-z]*\)'` # Hallo
echo `expr "$Stext" : '.*World'`      # 11
```

Although both search for a word, *I think*, both don't return what they find. Why?

Comment: `expr` is not bash functionality at all -- it's an external tool that isn't part of the shell. Consequently, its behavior is not guaranteed to be consistent on a given version of bash when installed on different platforms, beyond the minimal guarantees provided by the POSIX sh standard (guarantees which don't promise any regex syntax beyond BRE). Also, being external means it's *far* slower to execute, requiring a `fork()` to kick off a subshell and an `exec()` to replace that shell with an external executable.

Comment: In addition to `expr` being an external tool, you are echoing the results of calling the command in a subshell, making it doubly inefficient. These calls should be unwrapped, e.g. `expr "$Stext" : '^\(.[a-z]*\)'`. (see https://superuser.com/questions/1352850/what-is-wrong-with-echo-stuff-or-echo-stuff for a thorough explanation)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Both expressions are equivalent, the difference is the regular expression you use:

```
$ echo `expr "$Stext" : '^\(.[a-z]*\)'`
Hallo
$ echo `expr "$Stext" : '^.[a-z]*'`
5
$ echo `expr "$Stext" : '\(.*World\)'`
Hallo World
$ echo `expr "$Stext" : '.*World'`
11
```

As you can see, parentheses is what makes the difference to either return the length of the match or the match itself.

You can find more examples in [Chapter 10](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation @jcollado :) I was using the docs that you provided, but somehow did not get this parentheses functionality. The Bash-Scripting guide is not too easy to digest.

Comment: As this question is about [tag:bash], prefer to use *builtin* regex as [@kev suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9602260/1765658) instead of *fork to `/usr/bin/expr`*!

Answer (score 76):

You can use the `BASH_REMATCH` variable in `bash` to get the matched string:

```
$ Stext="Hallo World"
$ [[ $Stext =~ ^.[a-z]* ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
Hallo
$ [[ $Stext =~ ^(.[a-z]*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
Hallo
```

> Substrings matched by parenthesized subexpressions within the regular expression are saved in the array variable **BASH_REMATCH**. The element of BASH_REMATCH with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression. The element of BASH_REMATCH with index n is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.

Answer (score 0):

For quick string searches ... One option is grep.
If not found, returns empty, else it is a match:

```
found=`echo $big | grep -e $short`

if [ ! -z $found ]; then echo 'There is a match'; else echo 'No no'; fi
```