# expr: Regex not detecting valid expression

Tags: regex, bash, expr

I'm trying to create a script that automatically looks for plugged in devices and makes a compressed backup of it. However, I'm having trouble finding the correct way on how to use `expr`:

```
#!/bin/bash

MountText=`mount`
# Show result of regex search
expr "$MountText" : '\/dev\/(sd[^a])\d on [\S]+\/[\s\S]+? type'
```

The expression by itself is `\/dev\/(sd[^a])\d on [\S]+\/[\s\S]+? type`, and captures the device name (sd*), while excluding mounts relating to sda.

I drafted the regex on [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3ctqf) (regex shared in link), [and used what `mount` dumped (gist)](https://gist.github.com/MathManiac0/dfc3f1c50d8fc2ec3e4f).

For some reason, it only gives this odd error:

```
0
```

I looked around, and I [found this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597751/using-match-to-find-substrings-in-strings-with-only-bash). It didn't help me too much, because now it's implying that `expr` didn't recognize the parentheses I used to capture the device, and it also believed that the expression didn't capture anything!

I'm really confused. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regular expressions only work within languages, shells use wildcards or globs, please google these terms for the shell you are using,                 **echo $SHELL **

Comment: Thanks, didn't hear any information that `expr` uses globs. Though, I don't get what you mean by **echo $SHELL**, because I mentioned both in tags and in the hashbang that I'm using bash.

Comment: @ArifBurhan Also, I checked the `man` pages, and it says that the phrase `expr STRING : REGEXP` uses regular expressions.

Comment: `echo $(...)` is almost always redundant; there's no reason to capture the output of a command just to output it.

Comment: @chepner I commented that I wanted to see what It would produce. If I immediately put it into a script, it might have dangerous consequences.

Comment: No, it would have exactly the same effect: its output would go to standard output.

Comment: @chepner Oh... right...

Comment: The 0, by the way, is just the count of matching characters. (The errors noted in my answer cause your regular expression to not have a capture group and not match the given text.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note with `expr`:

1. The regular expression is implicitly anchored at the beginning of the string (as if you started the expression with `^`).
2. The capture group is indicated with escaped parentheses, `\(...\)`.
3. Only basic regular expressions are supported. Specifically, `\s`, `\S`, and `+?` are not supported.

The following will match the *one* device.

```
expr "$MountText" : '.*/dev/\(sd[^a]\)[[:digit:]] on '
```

---

Note that you don't need to use `expr` with `bash`, which has regular-expression matching built in.

```
regex='/dev/(sd[^a])[[:digit:]] on '
mount | while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
```

Comment: This gives the same error as before, so while some of this might help me, it still doesn't work. Did you test it out with the gist I had?

Comment: Sorry, tried to do too much from memory. Updating, but there is one caveat: you can only capture the first device that matches, not any more. (The non-greedy `+?` operator isn't supported, but would be unnecessary anyway.)

Comment: This works! I don't believe I will need to find other devices, but if I need to, I think I can use string manipulation to remove the captured line. Thanks so much!